# How to override a part of the style in the site.master page?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am developing an ASP.NET web application which in its site master (in the ContentPlaceHolder3) I put some css style which should apply to the whole website. Part from this style is the following:

```
.Welcome { 
width:531px; 
margin:5px 15px; 
float:left; 
padding:5px 10px; 
}
.Welcome ul { 
width:250px; 
float: left; 
margin:5px 3px; 
padding:0; 
list-style:none; 
}
.Welcome li {
background:url(images/ul_li.gif) left no-repeat;
padding:5px 20px; 
margin:0; 
font: normal 12px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; /* the original font-size was 11px. */ 
color:#5c5c5c; 
}
```

Now, in one of the website pages, I want to put some content inside that ContentPlaceHolder with the following specific style:

```
/*body { font: 0.8em Arial, sans-serif; }*/
        .tipsMenu { padding: 0; clear: both; }
        .tipsMenu li { display: inline; }
        .tipsMenu li a { background: #ccf; padding: 10px; float:left; border-right: 1px solid #ccf; border-bottom: none; text-decoration: none; color: #000; font-weight: bold;}
        .tipsMenu li.active a { background: #eef; }
        .tipsContent { float: left; clear: both; border: 1px solid #ccf; border-top: none; border-left: none; background: #eef; padding: 10px 20px 60px; width: 400px; }
```

***EDIT:***
**When I tried to do it, I got some style from the CSS file that is in the site.master page. So how can I override the style in the master page with the inline style?**

Comment: what do you mean with embedded? you mean inline styling? (css within the html tag)

Comment: When you say "got some style from the one embedded," what do you mean?  Which styles are coming from the Master page that you'd like to override?  The way your example shows, it looks like the .Welcome class would be assigned to a container, perhaps a div, and with the way CSS works, any li within that .Welcome container would have the rules applied.  Can you perhaps add some of your resulting HTML so that we can see the structure?

Comment: add !important in your content css, ex: .tipsMenu li a { background: #ccf !important;}, use that after each css property that you don't want to get overridden

Comment: @rs. this is what I want. I added it but still the background of <li> from the Site.Master appears. What is the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from making sure the specific style is loaded after the one embedded in the site.master page, you can try a couple of things:

**1.** Check the [css specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) of your new styles. Basically you need to make sure that the selectors used in your new styles are more specific than the ones used in the other stylesheet. In short, inline styles are more specific than ids, ids are more specific than classes and classes are more specific than html elements. e.g.:

```
#selector {
    // High specificity
}
.selector1 .selector2 .selector3 {
    // Less specificity than #selector, #selector styles applied
}
```

**2.** Add the `!important` clause to the styles. This overrides the specificity rules and forces the browser to use the important style. Although easier, this method isn't recommended for the sake of maintainability, among other reasons. like this:

```
.tipsMenu { padding: 0 !important; clear: both !important; }
.tipsMenu li { display: inline !important; }
```

Comment: Actually i cant use id or inline style because dont know the actual  html element but your second solution works like a charm.